# Where do I install my hairpin legs on this 8 foot long butcher block for my new workstation desk?

Tags: wood, screws, desk

So this is my first DYI wood project for my new workstation desk. I purchased this Baltic birch [butcher block](https://www.lowes.com/pd/The-Baltic-Butcher-Block-The-Baltic-Butcherblock-8-ft-Unfinished-Natural-Straight-Butcher-Block-Birch-Kitchen-Countertop/1000815502) and finished it myself. Not bad for my first go! It's 8 feet wide, 25" deep and 1.75 (1" 3/4) thick. It's a heavy boy.

For my legs I purchased [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072R2PNX3) 28 inch ones. They're solid but the 1 inch dry wall screws that arrived with them are poor quality so I'm going to pick up some wood screws.

Questions:

1. Where should I install the legs from the edges? It says 2 inches from the edge. Will that be enough for an 8 foot wide heavy butcher block? I don't see a problem with bowing in the center. Is there a rule of thumb for installing legs? I'm worried I'm gonna mess it up.
2. The holes in the leg plates are 1/4" in diameter. The desk is 1.75 (1" 3/4) thick. What kind wood screw size will do? Also, do you recommend I drill a pilot holes for birch wood?

Apologies for the super newb questions. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Do a search for similar desks and see where / how the legs are positioned, then consider any local issues to you.

Comment: I'd be more concerned about it being wobbly on those legs than about any sort of sag. It will _look_ nice (if you're into that style leg, I'm not so much), but it gives me the overall impression of being rickety. You've got a _long_, _heavy_ desk top on some very spindly supports - if you bump into the 25" end, the whole thing may well wobble along the 96" length, knocking over things on the desktop.

Comment: Yes to pilot holes. #10 or #12 pan head, 1-1/2" long. Subtleties in leg positioning aren't going to matter. If, as @FreeMan suggests, the desk has wobble problems, you could put two struts on the back legs that form triangles. Or you could tie it to a wall with a bracket if you had a wall handy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! you were right about the legs. I ended up going 3 inches in from the sides and 2 inches up. The legs are heavy metal and the desk feels incredibly solid. No wobble with sheer force.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate maybe make that an answer so the OP can accept it and this question can be closed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes to pilot holes. #10 or #12 pan head screws, 1-1/2" long.

Subtleties in leg positioning aren't going to matter. If, as @FreeMan suggests, the desk has wobble problems, you could put two struts on the back legs that form triangles. Or you could tie it to a wall with a bracket if you had a wall handy.

For anyone facing the same questions about sag, the Sagulator, http://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/ is a great resource to see if a given piece of wood or wood product will sag under a particular design load. If the OP had a flimsier piece of wood, that might have guided the positioning of the legs or changed the design.